# How to load GNOME before login?

Tags: unity, gnome

I installed GNOME 3 with the theme Paper, but when I boot with Ubuntu the login screen is still styled as Unity. Not a terrible problem, but is there a way to load GNOME before logging in?

Comment: Take a look  [Here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47347/preloading-gnome-shell-before-getting-login-dialog-from-gdm-is-it-possible).

Answer (score 4):

I assume you want to use GDM *(Gnome styled login page - right)* instead of LightDM (Unity/Xfce/LXDE depending on theme - left)

[image: LightDM screenshot & GDM screenshot]

you either need to install GDM with this command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
```

or configure it to be used instead of lightdm

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

with either command when you reach this step:

[image: Choose <code>gdm</code> or <code>lightdm</code>]

select `gdm` with the arrow keys,press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to select `<OK>` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now upon reboot (and perhaps logout) you should be able to use GDM. To switch back run the above `dpkg-reconfigure` command again and select `lightdm`.

Also, if you want to change the GDM background, edit `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/noise-texture.png` to a picture the size your display in PNG format with the same name, having backed up `noise-texture.png`